# Trouble retrieving Firebase data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Okay, so I'm trying to create a follower/following functionality(not sure best approach) and I keep running into issues when it comes to retrieving the data from the Firebase database. I'm using a recyclerView which shows all users, each User having a follow/following button. The issue I'm running into is checking if the user is already following or not. I will elaborate with code below

ViewHolder for RecyclerView

```
@Override
        public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.artist_list_single, parent, false);
            TextView username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.all_users_name);
            username.setTypeface(notes_font);

            return new UserViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Users model) {

            final String current_uid = currentUser.getUid();
            final String user_uid = getRef(position).getKey();
            final String test = mUserDatabase.child(current_uid).child("following").child(user_uid).getKey();

            final Button follow_following = (Button) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.follow_button);
            follow_following.setTypeface(notes_font);

            follow_following.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (!test.equals(user_uid)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mUserDatabase.child(current_uid).child("following").child(user_uid).setValue("true").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    mUserDatabase.child(user_uid).child("follower").child(current_uid).setValue("true");
                                    follow_following.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_button);
                                    follow_following.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                                    follow_following.setText("Following");
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else if (test.equals(user_uid)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                .setTitle("Unfollow?")
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        mUserDatabase.child(current_uid).child("following").child(user_uid).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    follow_following.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_outline);
                                                    follow_following.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_theme));
                                                    follow_following.setText("Follow");
                                                } else {
                                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                                .setCancelable(false);
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                }
            });

                holder.setName(model.getName());
                holder.setThumbImage(model.getThumbImage());
                holder.setStatus(model.getStatus());


            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), All_Profiles.class);
                    profileIntent.putExtra("user_uid", user_uid);
                    startActivity(profileIntent);
                }
            });
        }

    };
```

So when retrieving the test String, whether the User_uid is in the database or not, it detects that test.equals(user_uid) is true.. not sure where I went wrong there.
So next I tried using a ValueEventListening to retrieve data with onDataChange()
like this

```
@Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Users model) {

            final String current_uid = currentUser.getUid();
            final String user_uid = getRef(position).getKey();
            final String test = mUserDatabase.child(current_uid).child("following").child(user_uid).getKey();

            mUserDatabase.child(current_uid).child("following").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    testing = dataSnapshot.child(user_uid).getKey();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            final Button follow_following = (Button) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.follow_button);
            follow_following.setTypeface(notes_font);

            follow_following.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mUserDatabase.child(current_uid).child("following").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            testing = dataSnapshot.child(user_uid).getKey();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                    if (!testing.equals(user_uid)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), testing, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mUserDatabase.child(current_uid).child("following").child(user_uid).setValue("true").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    mUserDatabase.child(user_uid).child("follower").child(current_uid).setValue("true");
                                    follow_following.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_button);
                                    follow_following.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                                    follow_following.setText("Following");
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else if (testing.equals(user_uid)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), testing, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                .setTitle("Unfollow?")
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        mUserDatabase.child(current_uid).child("following").child(user_uid).setValue("false").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    follow_following.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_outline);
                                                    follow_following.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_theme));
                                                    follow_following.setText("Follow");
                                                } else {
                                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                                .setCancelable(false);
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                }
            });

                holder.setName(model.getName());
                holder.setThumbImage(model.getThumbImage());
                holder.setStatus(model.getStatus());


            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), All_Profiles.class);
                    profileIntent.putExtra("user_uid", user_uid);
                    startActivity(profileIntent);
                }
            });
        }
```

note: I called it twice because, calling it only once before onClick only retrieved key of first user for some reason. and calling it only once during each onClick crashed. calling it twice kind of worked for me except each time i press the button it doesnt update the key till I click it twice.. all in all Im really at a loss. please excuse my ignorance as I'm still learning, I know my code is not perfect(or even close lol) so please keep that in mind. also, i've been reading official documentation on Firebase and Android about everything I'm trying to do for over a week now, I wouldn't be coming here if I didn't. Thank You all in advanced for any help you may provide :)

here is a picture of my database
[image: Firebase Database]

Comment: could you add a picture of your database structure so we can have a better idea of whats happening?

Comment: whoops, yes I just added it. I'm sorry, i meant to include it